# Is there a way to automatically convert a MySQL table to a class so as to leverage Pydantic?

Tags: mysql, pydantic

I have a MySQL database. There is a table in this MySQL database called "Persons". It is defined like so

```
CREATE TABLE Persons (
    PersonID int,
    LastName varchar(255),
    FirstName varchar(255),
    Address varchar(255),
    City varchar(255)
);
```

I want to add an entry to this table with a dictionary like `{'PersonID': 5, 'LastName': 'McHenry', 'FirstName': 'Lana', 'Address': '55 Hargrove St', 'City': 'San Fransisco'}`

I want to validate that that dictionary is okay for entry with Pydantic. From what I have read, I would need to first define a class that is analogous to the MySQL table like so.

```
class Persons:
    PersonID: int
    LastName: varchar(255)
    FirstName: varchar(255)
    Address: varchar(255)
    City: varchar(255)
```

Is there a way to automatically generate that class definition from the MySQL database? I see that there is something called [codverter](https://codverter.com/blog/articles/tutorials/20190715-create-class-from-database-table.html), but this seems like a very clunky option (especially if I don't have a the CREATE TABLE SQL code on hand).

More generally, am I conceiving of this problem correctly?

Comment: What language are you programming in? In Python you can use SQLAlchemy for an OOP interface to SQL tables.

Comment: I know of SQLAlchemy, but I don't see how it solves the issue presented here, unless there is a way to use SQLAlchemy to convert a mySQL table into a class.

Comment: I don't know if there's a way to automatically convert a MySQL table to a SqlAlchemy model. But you can write the model by hand, and then I think you should be able to validate with Pydantic.

Comment: Yeah, I can see how that would work. It's just that any time the MySQL table is changed (and it does tend to go through frequent minor tweaks) someone would have to make a corresponding, precise change to the SqlAlchemy model, which is not an ideal workflow.

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/sqlacodegen/ - library to automatically generate the sqlalchemy model from the DB